# ObjectInputStream End of file exception ignores print statements

Tags: java, sockets, eof

I'm reading a file from a Google glass device to a PC through a java socket.
The rest of my code is being ignored due to an eof exception thrown by a catch statement. An ideas how I can fix this?

Code: to receive an image (and put it in a simple jfame)

```
ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(
clientimage.getInputStream());

System.out.println("infrom: "  + inFromServer.readObject() + "\n");

System.out.println("infrom bytes: " + inFromServer.readByte() + "\n");
System.out.println("infrom something: " + inFromServer.readUTF());


File temp = (File) inFromServer.readObject();
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(temp);
System.out.println("image height: " + image.getHeight());


JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.getContentPane().add(label);
f.pack();
f.setLocation(200,200);
f.setVisible(true);
```

The client is taking a picture and sending the file to the PC:

```
Socket pic_socket = new Socket(ip, 50505);
ObjectOutputStream imageToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(pic_socket.getOutputStream());
imageToServer.writeObject(pictureToSend.getAbsoluteFile());
imageToServer.close();
```

My output is:

> Connection starting ..
>   image srv connected to: /192.168.1.104
>   infrom: \storage\emulated\0\DCIM\Camera\20151209_110536_982.jpg

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? And what has *written* the data? (If it wasn't an `ObjectOutputStream`, you shouldn't be using `ObjectInputStream`...)

Comment: I believe the line that's throwing the exception is 
`ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientimage.getInputStream());` 


I think it's just not "stopping" when its done. I'm not really sure.  The sender is taking a picture and storing the File in an ObjectOutputStream, as follows:


`Socket pic_socket = new Socket(ip, 50505);
ObjectOutputStream imageToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(pic_socket.getOutputStream());
imageToServer.writeObject(pictureToSend.getAbsoluteFile());
imageToServer.close();`

Comment: Well you should be able to tell, from the stack trace and by debugging. But given that you're only calling `writeObejct()`, and just once, what do you expect `readByte` and `readUTF` to do? I'd expect the problem to be the `readByte()` call.

Comment: The readByte and UTF calls were just to see if I can get some information about the picture. Ideally I would like to get the picture in a jFrame, and just print out the height and width. I did end up taking out the print stacktrace on the catch statement for the exception, just to try and keep the program running.

Comment: Well you haven't shown the catch block at all - and currently it's clear that your code *will* throw an exception due to asking for more data that's been read. You really, really need to give more information about the exception. You need to be *sure* where it's being thrown. And for now, get rid of the readUTF and readByte calls. In fact, given the logging, it strongly looks like those *are* the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you've shown indicates that this line is working:

```
System.out.println("infrom: "  + inFromServer.readObject() + "\n");
```

And this line is throwing an exception:

```
System.out.println("infrom bytes: " + inFromServer.readByte() + "\n");
```

Which makes sense, because you're only writing a single object, and then closing the stream. Your code *should* be:

```
File temp;
try (ObjectInputStream inFromServer =
        new ObjectInputStream(clientimage.getInputStream()) {
    temp = (File) inFromService.readObject();
}
System.out.println("infrom: "  + temp + "\n");
```

... and then get rid of the calls to `readByte()` and `readUTF()`. They correspond to data that hasn't been written. Note that with the above code, you're also only calling `readObject()` once, which is crucial as only a single object has been written.

Comment: My output seems to recognize temp (the output hasn't changed) which I think might be a good sign. The only other question I have is related to the  BufferedImage, if you don't mind. I do have a print statement to show the height of the image, but I'm not confident on whether or not that code is running.

Comment: @user2852171: At this point you *really* need to start learning how to use a debugger, so you can step through the code. Stack Overflow isn't designed for "This bit isn't working... now this bit isn't working... now this bit isn't working" questions.